# Specify encoding when Open for input VB

Tags: file, vba, encoding

I'm trying to open a file for input in Excel with this line :

```
Open tmpNmFichier For Input Shared As #iFnum
```

The problem is that my file has some characters like : "é", "à" ... When I'm parsing the file with :

```
Dim s As String

Line Input #iFnum, s
If Len(s) > 0 Then
     v = Split(s, tmpSeparateur)
Else
    ReDim v(-1 To -1)
End If
```

my characters "é" ... are transformed in : "Ã¨" or "Ã..."

Do you have any idea how i can explicit the encoding of my file or something like that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Use `FileSystemObject` instead**

```
Public Function GetContent(fpath$) As String
    'REFERENCES:
    'Microsoft Scripting Runtime // Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim fso As New Scripting.FileSystemObject, content$
    If fso.FileExists(fpath) Then
        content = fso.OpenTextFile(fpath, ForReading, False, TristateTrue).ReadAll()
        GetContent = content
    Else
        MsgBox "Invalid file path."
        GetContent = vbNullChar
    End If
End Function
```

**values**

```
TristateUseDefault -2 Opens the file using the system default. 
TristateTrue -1 Opens the file as Unicode. 
TristateFalse  0 Opens the file as ASCII.
```

Comment: **Additional tip:**  If you use VBA to save using this method then you should also use it to read.  I had a situation where I was saving with `fso.OpenTextFile TriStateTrue` but reading with `Line Input`, and the first two characters in the file were imported as `ÿþ`.  `ÿþ` is the [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_Order_Mark) of a [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) Little Endian encoded file. That is a way to signal it is a Unicode file and the VBA *Line Input* wasn't aware of that.  Using the fso method to read with TriStateTrue solved my problem.